# Testing a HTTP API is working with a boto3 Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm not too sure how the formatting works with using json and boto3 in the same file. The function works how it should but I don't know how to get a response from an API without an `Internal server error`.

I don't know if it is permissions or the code is wrong.

```py
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table('Visit_Count')

    input = {'Visits': 1}

    table.put_item(Item=input)
    
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200
        body: json.dumps("Hello, World!")
    }
```

Comment: `'body'`, not `body`, and you're missing a comma after `200`.  You really should run this in the Lambda Console or using the [sam cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html) so you can see syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `body` it should be `'body'`. Other than that you should check [CloudWatch logs for any further lambda errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html).

Comment: I also tried it, went to my API gateway URL and added /getClick method and I got an internal server error. I think this may be a permissions issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Anon and Marcin were right, I just tried it and it worked
Your Lambda role also need to have `dynamodb:PutItem`

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table('Visit_Count')

    input = {'Visits': 1}

    table.put_item(Item=input)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```